# Can not send data from client to server

Tags: java, server, socket.io, io, client

> I can't send data from the client to the server. I checked and found out that the server didn't catch the data sending event from the client, but they connected to each other. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VshpW.png)
>
> ```
> // server
> public void startServer() {
>     Configuration config = new Configuration();
>     config.setPort(PORT_NUMBER);
>     server = new SocketIOServer(config);
>     server.addConnectListener(new ConnectListener() {
>           
>   @Override
>   public void onConnect(SocketIOClient arg0) {
>   textArea.append("One client connect \n");
> }
>           
>           
>           
> }); 
>   
>   server.addEventListener("register", Server_Model_Register.class, new dataListener<Server_Model_Register>() {
>
>       @Override
>       public void onData(SocketIOClient arg0, Server_Model_Register arg1, AckRequest arg2) throws Exception {
>           System.out.println( "data received");
>               
>       }
>
>           
>           
>       });
>       server.start();
>       textArea.append("Server has start on port : " + PORT_NUMBER + "\n" );
>   }
> ```

> ```
> //client
> public void startServer() throws URISyntaxException {
>     try {
>   System.out.println("start");
>   client = IO.socket("http://" + IP + ":"+ PORT_NUMBER);
>   client.connect();
>           
>   client.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
>       @Override
>             public void call(Object... args) {
>          System.out.println("Connected to server successfully.");
>                   }
>               }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
>       @Override
>        public void call(Object... args) {
>             System.out.println("Connection to server failed.");
>             for (Object arg : args) {
>                      System.out.println("Error message: " + arg);
>                       }
>                   }
>               });
>            
>            
>       } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
>           error(e);
>           
>       }
>   }
> ```

> this is action button register, then press data will process and emit to server. it was print Emited to server
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void register(Client_Model_Register data) {
>               
>      Client_Service.getInstance().getClient().emit("register", data, new Ack() {
>                   
>          @Override
>          public void call(Object... arg0) {
>   
>    if (arg0.length > 0) {
>                              
>         Object response = arg0[0];
>                               
>         if (response instanceof String) {
>         String message = (String) response;
>         System.out.println("Server response: " + message);
>                              
>     } 
>           } else {
>                  
>             System.out.println("No response from server.");
>           }
>                       
>   }
>  });
>               
>  System.out.println("Emited to server");
>               
>           }
> ```